# SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based - yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am trying to perform filter/search among multiple columns. I am stuck with this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: Columns/Parameters are 1-based

Any idea what is it?
The below code is my search model.

**My Code:**

```
$combo = explode('.',$this->storeNamesCombo);

$storeClasses = ArrayHelper::map(StoreClasses::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
$storeFamilies = ArrayHelper::map(StoreFamilies::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');
$storePlatforms = ArrayHelper::map(StorePlatforms::find()->all(), 'id', 'name');

$mc_search = [];
$mf_search = [];
$mp_search = [];

foreach($combo as $item){
    $temp_mc = array_search($item, $storeClasses);
    if($temp_mc !== False){ $mc_search[] = $temp_mc; }

    $temp_mf = array_search($item, $storeFamilies);
    if($temp_mf !== False){ $mf_search[] = $temp_mf; }

    $temp_mp = array_search($item, $storePlatforms);
    if($temp_mp !== False){ $mp_search[] = $temp_mf; }
}


if(!empty($mc_search)){
    foreach($mc_search as $item){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['or', '"storeNames"."classId"' => $item]);    
    }

}
if(!empty($mf_search)){
    foreach($mf_search as $item){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['or', '"storeNames"."familyId"' => $item]);    
    }
}
if(!empty($mp_search)){
    foreach($mp_search as $item){
        $query->andFilterWhere(['or', '"storeNames"."platformId"' => $item]);
    }
}

if(!empty($combo)){
    foreach($combo as $item){
        $query->where(['ilike', '"storeNames"."subFamilyName"', $item],
            ['ilike', '"storeNames"."variantName"', $item]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you add `or` in your `andFilterWhere`?

Comment: Seems i copied from old queries, the problem still remains after removing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your last statement to this:

```
if(!empty($combo)){
    foreach($combo as $item){
        $query->andWhere([
            'or',
            ['ilike', '"storeNames"."subFamilyName"', $item],
            ['ilike', '"storeNames"."variantName"', $item]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is gone, but there seems to be something wrong with search. It only searches when variantName is specified.I have to make search among all 5 columns.

Comment: Do you want a `or` search?

Comment: @5.1tat Hi, I have updated my answer to meet your requirement.

Comment: @5.1tat Do you mean that the 5 columns are `or` search, or just the last statement is `or` search?

Comment: And what if the 5 columns are are 'or' ?
That's not my requirement but if you can provide with it, it would be helpful.

Comment: You are welcome :). Just use `orFilterWhere` and `orWhere`.

Comment: Thanks mate :) that helped.